# Fetch Foreign Key Row Data With Sync

Tags: mysql, replication, symmetricds

I am using `SymmetricDS` for first time and i have two table to sync. 
1. `Session_Tbl` :-  this table sync from Store to Corp. I cant  make session_tbl bidirection.
2. `Products` :- This table sync in bidirection. Product Table is linked with Session_tbl with `PRODUCTS_SESSION` FOREIGN KEY.

```
CREATE TABLE SESSION_TBL (
    SESSION_ID VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    STATUS VARCHAR(15),
    CREATION_TIME DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    MODIFICATION_TIME DATETIME ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (SESSION_ID)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS (
    PRODUCT_ID VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    REFERENCE VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    CODE VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CODETYPE VARCHAR(10),
    NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    SESSION_ID VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (PRODUCT_ID),   
    CONSTRAINT PRODUCTS_SESSION FOREIGN KEY (SESSION_ID) REFERENCES SESSION_TBL(SESSION_ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When i insert data in store it sync to corp as well, becasue sesison_tbl will sync store to corp and product table is bidirectional. 
But when i insert any product in products table what time i am getting below exception because session id is not exist in store session_tbl:-

```
org.jumpmind.db.sql.SqlException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Is there any configuration in `SymmetricDS` which can fetch the Foreign Key Data file sending product data?

**EDIT**

Added sym table data :-

```
insert into SYM_NODE (node_id, node_group_id, external_id, sync_enabled, created_at_node_id)
  values ('000', 'backoffice', '000', 1, 'server');

  insert into SYM_NODE (node_id, node_group_id, external_id, sync_enabled, created_at_node_id)
  values ('001', 'pos', '001', 1, 'server');

insert into SYM_NODE_IDENTITY values ('000');

insert into sym_node_security (node_id,node_password,registration_enabled,registration_time,initial_load_enabled,initial_load_time,created_at_node_id)
 values ('000','5d1c92bbacbe2edb9e1ca5dbb0e661',0,current_timestamp,0,current_timestamp,'server');

 insert into sym_node_security (node_id,node_password,registration_enabled,registration_time,initial_load_enabled,initial_load_time,created_at_node_id)
 values ('001','5d1c92bbacbe2edb9e1ca5dbb0e661',0,current_timestamp,0,current_timestamp,'server');

 -- CREATE GROUP 

 insert into SYM_NODE_GROUP
        (node_group_id, description)
        values ('pos', 'A retail pos node');

insert into SYM_NODE_GROUP
        (node_group_id, description)
        values ('backoffice', 'A backoffice node');

    -- CREATE GROUP LINK

insert into SYM_NODE_GROUP_LINK
(source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id, data_event_action)
      values ('pos', 'backoffice', 'P');

insert into SYM_NODE_GROUP_LINK
(source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id, data_event_action)
      values ('backoffice', 'pos', 'W');

    insert into SYM_CHANNEL (channel_id, processing_order, max_batch_size, max_batch_to_send,
             extract_period_millis, batch_algorithm,data_loader_type, enabled, description)
         values ('pos_to_backoffice_default', 1, 1000, 10, 0, 'default','default', 1, 'pos_to_backoffice_default one directional');


insert into SYM_TRIGGER (trigger_id, source_table_name,
          channel_id,sync_on_incoming_batch, last_update_time, create_time)
                  values ('pos_to_backoffice_default', 'SESSION_TBL', 'pos_to_backoffice_default',1, current_timestamp, current_timestamp);


     insert into SYM_CHANNEL (channel_id, processing_order, max_batch_size, max_batch_to_send,
         extract_period_millis, batch_algorithm,data_loader_type, enabled, description)
     values ('twoway_default', 10, 1000, 10, 0, 'default','default', 1, 'twoway_default bidirectional');

 insert into SYM_TRIGGER (trigger_id, source_table_name,
          channel_id,sync_on_incoming_batch, last_update_time, create_time)
                  values ('twoway_default', 'PRODUCTS', 'twoway_default',1, current_timestamp, current_timestamp);

insert into SYM_TRIGGER_ROUTER
        (trigger_id, router_id, initial_load_order, create_time,
        last_update_time) values ('pos_to_backoffice_default', 'pos-2-backoffice', 1, current_timestamp,
        current_timestamp);

        insert into SYM_TRIGGER_ROUTER
        (trigger_id, router_id, initial_load_order, create_time,
        last_update_time) values ('twoway_default', 'backoffice-2-pos', 1, current_timestamp,
        current_timestamp);

        insert into SYM_TRIGGER_ROUTER
        (trigger_id, router_id, initial_load_order, create_time,
        last_update_time) values ('twoway_default', 'pos-2-backoffice', 1, current_timestamp,
        current_timestamp);

insert into SYM_ROUTER (router_id,
        source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id,router_type, create_time,
        last_update_time) values ('backoffice-2-pos','backoffice', 'pos','default',
        current_timestamp, current_timestamp);

              insert into SYM_ROUTER (router_id,
        source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id,router_type, create_time,
        last_update_time) values ('pos-2-backoffice','pos', 'backoffice','default',
        current_timestamp, current_timestamp);
```

Thanks 
Anchit

Comment: What are the sym_trigger and sym_trigger_router rows for these two tables? First one should extract data, and another one link it to routers in both directions

Comment: I have added information as requested with edit.

Comment: there's sym_router missing

Comment: I have added SYM_ROUTER.

Comment: it all seems fine. has the store successfuly registered at corp? what's inside sym_node table at corp?

Comment: registeration is fine, Dont you thing SESSION_TBL need to be bidirectional? or is that fine? I have added sym_node table and all other remain table in edit

Comment: you're not supposed to insert values into sym_node and sym_node_security. values are inserted on registration of a client (store).

Comment: i added this entry because without this , registration was getting failed.  After it sync work fine if i add any data in session_tbl and product table in client(store). But when i insert data in product table with some new session row its get failed because session table is one directional and i am just think how symmetic will get to know that it need to sync session table first to avoid this error while sync product table.

Comment: there are no uni or bidirectional tables. it's up to you how to configure the syncing. what's the exception?

Comment: below exception because session table data (of corp ) is not there in clients(store) session_tbl org.jumpmind.db.sql.SqlException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: have you checked at the source if values from both tables have been successfuly extracted to sym_data and then routed by linking sym_data with sym_data_event and sym_outgoing_batch?

Comment: sym_outgoing_batch have products data but not session data

Comment: ok. is data extracted to sym_data?

Comment: I can see the product data in sym_data table

Comment: so, it means that the sym_router and sym_trigger_router haven't been correctly defined and the extracted data from sym_data hasn't been linked to sym_data_event and sym_outgoing_batch

Comment: that's what i am trying it figure out

Comment: can you please contact me on anchitpancholi6868@gmail.com ? I would like to discuss something.